# How would you write a complex query in laravel 5?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Hello guys I wonder if this query I wrote with laravel's syntax is actually make sense.

What I am trying to do: I got two tables. One is users table. Second is the dependent table for users. its called user's_thoughts. I want to pull the top best results of posts from users table. and this top results are based on how many likes that particular post had. This like column is in user's_thoughts table.

Here is what I have put together for this:

```
$results=DB::table('users')->join('user_thoughts', 'users.id', '=', 'user_thoughts.user_id')->select('users.post_id', 'users.post_title', 'users.posts', 'user_thought.like')-get();
```

Now, after this query which selects from both tables, I am going to see which post had the highest amount of likes.

```
$count = DB::table('user_thoughts')->count('likes');
$highest = DB::table('user_thoughts')->max('$count');
```

Now, here I would loop the results out.

```
$show = foreach ($highest as $cherrypicked => $topones) {
       echo $topones;
}
```

Have I followed this correctly? What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you include the raw SQL query which you want to execute using Laravel?

Comment: try learning from [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent). Laravel is known for its MVC architecture. try using model.

Comment: Laravel provide a strong package for model and realationship you could save a lot of effort by checking this out

Comment: @NitishKumar but what do you guys thing, did I do this right though?

Comment: I do not see any connection between your first query (`$results=DB::table('users')->join`...) and the other two queries. You don't even need the first query (where you join the two tables).

Comment: @RaminK you need a correct output right so check your output you have to tell us its correct or wrong but it seems wrong you won't get correct out put you need . tell your correct requirement we can try

Comment: @Hamel Raj so basically I want to show posts from users table but these posts have their likes recorded in the user_thoughts table. Now, since this is a featured list, all the posts which have been liked a lot need to be outputted at the top of the page. So can you please help me? thanks.

Comment: if you show your tables i can help you @RaminK